# Save RAM when using dante proxy

Tags: proxy, memory, socks, dante

I have a small server that I run dante socks proxy on to route torrent traffic through it.
Now the problem is, that for each connection dante seems to create a new program/thread and it uses nearly my whole 256MB of RAM.
Is there any way to make the memory footprint smaller?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault, this Q&A site is intended for System Admins who work in a professional setting.  Your question seems to indicate a setup not used in a professional setting, therefore it is off-topic.  Please read the FAQ before posting again.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try [openvpn](http://openvpn.net) instead.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @rnxrx - it's a tool. openvpn comes with excellent how to. use case varies, i think it would be pointless to provide sample configuration not knowing detailed needs of the author of the original question. would you copy&paste Apache documentation if someone was asking how to host few static files on a home server?